# Disable Index Title that are not available in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I want to disable the index title for those letter that are not available in my `UITableView`.

Just like below image:

[image]

Is It possible to do that.

I use this code to make index title white color but not able to give specific title to gray color:

```
for(UIView *view in [tblExerciseView subviews])
    {
        if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewIndex"])
        {
            [view performSelector:@selector(setIndexColor:) withObject:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in two way,

First only show present letters in your index view.

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return YOUR_LETTERS;
}
```

Second thing you can do make your own view and add it on table view with some labels and u can provide your desired color to that label.